# VSC How to setup a debug configuration for a docker-contained React/Next.js App

Tags: reactjs, docker, visual-studio-code, next.js

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nextjs-with-typescript",
  "version": "5.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies":{
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "react": "latest"
  },
  "@types/react": "latest"
}
```

This is how I start the app:

1. `docker-compose up` to set up and run a docker-based database
2. `npm run dev` to start a `next` server
3. then start a new Chrome to `localhost:3000` to access app
4. launch.json, add `Attach by Process ID` to debug the api backend

Breakpoint set inside index.tsx not hit, adding `Attach to Chrome` won't help. Chrome F12, Sources tab not showing any front-end code.

I'd like to add one configuration into Launch.json be able to one-click start debugging both front-end Chrome react/tsx and back-end .ts inside VSC.

My VSC:

```
Version: 1.63.1 (system setup)
Commit: fe719cd3e5825bf14e14182fddeb88ee8daf044f
Date: 2021-12-14T02:13:54.292Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

Comment: Any luck setting up debugger in VS Code using Docker?